# Automatically print/save NUnit XML output

Tags: .net-2.0, nunit, automated-tests

I've setup some Nunit tests for validating my statistical formulas within my .net v2 application, for company records i need to have a printed copy of this output.  Is anyone aware of any commands in NUnit to automatically print the XML to default printer?

If printing isn't possible saving to a folder may work for us.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NUnit console automatically gives the results as xml. To state your own name on the xml file, this is what you need to do:

> nunit-console /xml:someFileNameHere.xml yourFileWithNUnitTestsHere.dll

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm just getting started with NUnit and im surprised i can't run the GUI and export/print the xml at the same time.

I suppose i can setup a batch file to run both and run that on post build.

thanks again